# What happens when accessing an array with multiple different types: int16_t, int, and int64_t, in C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting

Suppose I have a dynamically allocated array as in

```
int64_t * arr; arr = new int64_t[M];
```

where M is of type int64_t and is large enough to handle the accessed value I show below in the subscript operator.

**Question**: What happens to each kind of integer and integer-multiplication in my subscript operator of `arr' when I access it with the following:

```
int16_t A = 12;
int B = INT_MAX;
int64_t N = int64_t(B)*int64_t(B) // This will store the correct value of 800^3 into N and will not cause wrap-around 

int64_t my_value = arr[N + B + A]

int64_t my_value_2 = arr[A + B + N]

int64_t my_value_3 = arr[B]

int64_t my_value_4 = arr[12L*(Nx+Nx*Ny+1)]
```

?

I am unsure of the rules for these different integer types are handled in the subscripting operator.  I am familiar with working with subscripting operators where all variables used in the operator are all of type `int' and are small enough that they will not overflow. I'm unsure of the behavior when there are multiple int types all called in the same operator, especially for large arrays where int64_t is required.

Comment: whether `N + B*B*B + A + N*B` overflows or not does not depend on whether you use it as argument to subscript.

Comment: Well, the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) apply, before the [subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) call.

Comment: If your platform's `int` is 16 bits (which is legal, according to the Standard), then the `B*B*B` in `int64_t my_value = arr[N + B*B*B + A + N*B]` ***will*** overflow.

Comment: Also note: On most common modern architectures, `int` is 32 bits and `B*B*B` will fit in an `int`. But if you're on a 16 bit `int` architecture, `B*B*B` in the subscript will evaluate at higher precedence than the operations that would cause type promotion, so wraparound would occur. Why you would use `B*B*B` there when `N * 2` or `N + N` would get the same result without the risk is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition operator (`+`) is left-to-right associative.  As a result, given

```
int16_t A;
int B;
int64_t N;
```

then `N + B + A` and `B + A + N` both have the same final result type, but the former uses `int64_t` (or `int`, if it is larger) to compute the subexpression `N + B` and the latter uses `int` (which cannot be smaller than `int16_t`) to compute the subexpression `B + A`.

If `B + A` overflows `int`, `B + A + N` will cause you problems that don't exist with `N + B + A`.

---

Note that `INT_MAX` can be 2<sup>15</sup>-1, 2<sup>31</sup>-1, 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (among other legal values) and therefore it is not portable to assume that `int64_t(INT_MAX)*int64_t(INT_MAX)` does not overflow.

Comment: This is definitely the answer to my question!  I can not mark it yet because I do not have enough rep.  If someone else can then I would appreciate it.  Thank you again!